# Sentencia SQL para ver buscar un dato en los ultimos 60 dias

Tags: php, mysql, sql

me ocupa lo siguiente:
Tengo la siguiente sentencia SQL

```
SELECT nro_transf, id 
FROM pagos 
WHERE  (nro_transf LIKE '%0012345') 
AND STR_TO_DATE(fecha_transf,'%Y-%m-%d %T')
BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 60 DAY) 
AND CURDATE()
```

Si efectuo la sentencia tal como la tengo no me da resultados

Pero si la ejecuto con solo:

```
SELECT nro_transf, id FROM pagos WHERE  (nro_transf LIKE '%0012345')
```

Me da todos los resultados de las distintas fechas existentes en mi tabla.

No logro dar la instruccion para que ejecute la busqueda del dato dado pero que dicha busqueda ocurra solo en los ultimos 60 dias de la columna `fecha_transf`

Comment: En el apartado del where remplaza tu where por   BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 60 DAY AND NOW()

Answer (score 0):

He utilizado la sentencia:

```
SELECT nro_transf, id FROM pagos WHERE  (nro_transf LIKE '%0012345') AND STR_TO_DATE(fecha_transf,'%Y-%m-%d %T')
 BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY) AND NOW()
```

Creo que la funcion que estaba tratando de utilizar no da los resultados esperados.

Tome la sugerencia de @Herrera